# Open a csv as a list of integers

Tags: python, csv, integer

I am a newbie trying to teach myself Python. I have a file with a bunch of numbers in it and I want to "import" them into a python list as integers (or at least that's what I think I want to do). I seem to be having a problem, but I don't understand what it is. Here is some detailed information on my problem and the code I've tried:

I have a DNA sequence (e.g. a string of ~ 150,000 letters) and I would like to have python go to a certain position in that string and then print the 150 letters to the left of that position, the letter at that position surrounded by square brackets, and then 150 letters to the right of that position. I need to do this for >100 positions in the string. I have a list of these positions in a separate file. I have figured out that Biopython has an object that will handle the very long string for me, and if I tell python what position I want (e.g. assign it by hand), I can slice this string and get the correct output. Now I want to be able to import my target positions from this other file and then have python iteratively go through that list and print the output to another file. The first part is where I am having some trouble.

I have tried the input file in several different formats. One like this:

```
500,1000,15000
```

And another one like this (all positions on separate lines):

```
500

1000

15000
```

Based on some other posts I read I have tried several things. Here is one:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
import csv

with open('Results.fa', 'a') as f1:
    Reference = SeqIO.read("GEO5FinalAssembly2SC.fa", "fasta") # Biopython
    DataFile = open('TestFile.csv', 'r')
    DataReader = csv.reader(DataFile)
    SNP = []
    for row in DataReader:
        SNP.append(row)
    for i in SNP:
        IA=i-151  #Creating the intervals
        IB=i-1
        JA=i+1
        JB=i+151
        Fragment = Reference.seq[IA:IB] + "[" + Reference.seq[i] + "]" + Reference.seq[JA:JB]
        F = str(Fragment)      #Need to turn Fragment into a string that can be written
        header = ">MINT_SNP" + str(i) + "\n"
        f1.write(header)
        f1.write(F)
        f1.write("\n")
```

This returns the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./ReferenceSplitter3.py", line 15, in <module>
    IA=i-151  #Creating the intervals
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'
```

I also tried this:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
import csv

with open('Results.fa', 'a') as f1:
    Reference = SeqIO.read("GEO5FinalAssembly2SC.fa", "fasta")
    with open('TestFile.txt', 'r') as Input:
        rows = csv.reader(Input, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
        SNP = [[item for number, item in enumerate(row)] for row in rows]       
    for i in SNP:
        IA=i-151  #Creating the intervals
        IB=i-1
        JA=i+1
        JB=i+151
        Fragment = Reference.seq[IA:IB] + "[" + Reference.seq[i] + "]" + Reference.seq[JA:JB]
        F = str(Fragment)      #Need to turn Fragment into a string that can be written
        header = ">SNP" + str(i) + "\n"
        f1.write(header)
        f1.write(F)
        f1.write("\n")
```

This gives a similar error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./ReferenceSplitter4.py", line 13, in <module>
    IA=i-151  #Creating the intervals
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'
```

However, when I define a list of integers myself like this SNP = (500,1000,1500) it seems to work just fine. I wonder if I am missing some fundamental python concept here. Sorry if this is a really basic question, but any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: `SNP` is a list of rows, meaning a list of lists. It looks something like `[[1, 2, 3], [4,5,6]]` Maybe you want to flatten your input data into a list like `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`?

Comment: Also, your lack of naming conventions is rather confusing. In Python, it's preferred to use `snake_case` for variables, and `CamelCase` for classes. (Third-party libraries tend to be all over the place on this because most originated before the conventions settled down.)

Comment: I was wondering why 'SNP' had double square brackets, thanks for pointing out what that mean. Sorry, also for the naming conventions, I have to work on that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the input where they are all on the same line separated by commas (`500,1000,10000`), you can read it in with:

```
SNP = next(DataReader)
```

For the input where they are each on a different line, do:

```
SNP = []
for row in DataReader:
    SNP.append(row[0])
```

Either will set `SNP` to a list of numbers, like `[500, 1000, 15000]`, than you can then iterate over.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried these things, but I still can't seem to get it to work. Apparently I'm terrible at writing comments, too.

Comment: I ran this **DataFile = open('TestFile.csv', 'r')**; **DataReader = csv.reader(DataFile)**; **SNP = next(DataReader)** and got the same error 'IA=i-151  #Creating the intervals
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'' I also tried the other way and got the same error again. Sorry if I'm being dense here.

Comment: You need to turn `i` from a string to an int. You can do that as `i = int(i)` in the start of the for loop, `SNP = map(int, next(DataReader))` in the first of my solutions, or `SNP.append(int(row[0]))` in the second of my solutions.

Comment: Thanks again, for your help! I just figured that out too!

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else is ever interested in doing this (using Biopython), this should work. The script below will find the flanking region around a SNP. Thanks to David Robinson for the helpful suggestions!

```
from Bio import SeqIO
import csv

with open('Results.fa', 'a') as f1:
   reference = SeqIO.read("Reference.fa", "fasta")
   datafile = open('TestFile.csv', 'r')
   datareader = csv.reader(datafile)
   positions = next(datareader)
   snp = [int(i) for i in positions] #Convert strings in positions to integers
   for i in snp:
        IA=i-151  #Creating the intervals
        IB=i-1
        JA=i+1
        JB=i+151

        fragment = reference.seq[IA:IB] + "[" + reference.seq[i] + "]" + reference.seq[JA:JB]
        f = str(fragment)      #Need to turn Fragment into a string that can be written
        header = ">SNP" + str(i) + "\n"
        f1.write(header)
        f1.write(f)
        f1.write("\n")
```